I am confused with the way execution is supposed to take place. I do not understand why the code is not executed. I am using shelve
This is a code segment that begins line 261 in my file.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # main()
  print('Checkpoint 0')
  createShelve()
  print('Checkpoint 1')
  data = loadShelve()
  print('Checkpoint 2')
  for key in data.keys():
    print(key)

while debugging, I have added a bunch of print statements to createShelve and it looks exactly like this:
  def createShelve():
    global SHELVE_FILE
    filenames = getFilenames()
    data = {}
    print('Empty Data Now')
    for filename in filenames:
      build_data(filename, data=data)
      print('loaded file {}'.format(filename))
    print('Loading with {} keys'.format(len(data.keys())))


    recursionLimit = sys.getrecursionlimit()
    sys.setrecursionlimit(12657)  # used manual binary search to compute this
    print('Checkpoint A')
    try:
      print('Checkpoint B')
      with shelve.open(SHELVE_FILE) as result:
        result.update(data)
      print('File now contains data with {} keys'.format(len(data.keys())))
    except RecursionError:
      print('****Maximum recursion limit reached****')
      for ext in ('.bak', '.dat', '.dir'):
        print('Deleting {}'.format(filename + ext))
        os.unlink(filename + ext)
    print('Checkpoint C')
    sys.setrecursionlimit(recursionLimit)
    print('Checkpoint D')

Pointing directly at the problem here, I have 4 main print statements at checkpoints A, B, C, and D. Only A and B are printed and I still cannot think of any reason why the execution control will skip those lines. Also for the numeric checkpoints at the module level, only 'Checkpoint 0' is reached.
The only element of this code which I have not used before is the functions for setting recursion limit. I do not know if they could have some effect that is causing this. I have checked python's manual and I do not see something that might cause some effect. If you noticed from the checkpoints that were printed, it seems to suggest that only one of the setrecursionlimit calls were executed.
After I run the program, It executes and gives the following output but stops at that before closing without any errors. The data structure that I am attempting to save is a dictionary of keys which are the path to the html files and the corresponding tree of data that was processed from the html files. The question in this link is basically about the same problem. I will be looking to implement the solution there.
Shortened Output:
Checkpoint 0
Empty Data Now
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile001.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile002.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile003.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile004.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile005.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile006.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile007.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile008.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile009.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile010.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile011.html

<snip>    

loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile040.html
loaded file .\json_data\SomeFile041.html
Loading with 41 keys
Checkpoint A
Checkpoint B


I just found something new. Perharps, this is the reason, I don't know. I will dive into it now.

could you post what is being printed in the console in the question? So we can see the checkpoints that are printed. Also I don;t see any recursive code in what you posted. Why should the try block throw a RecursionError? You just call open and update.

@Elerium115, it is done

sys.setrecursionlimit(12657)  # used manual binary search to compute this - what do you mean with this code comment? What problem do you hope to solve by setting the recursion limit, and what is the reason for choosing this exact value (i.e., what was the basis for the calculation)?

sys.setrecursionlimit doesn't actually solve problems. It usually just turns a Python-level stack overflow into a much worse C stack overflow. That's likely happening here.

"Only A and B are printed and I still cannot think of any reason why the execution control will skip those lines. Also for the numeric checkpoints at the module level, only 'Checkpoint 0' is reached." - What happens after that? Do you get a Python exception, or an error from the operating system, or some other kind of warning? Does the program just quit right there? Does the program appear to hang/freeze? Something else?

@KarlKnechtel, a value of 15000 worked but a value of 10000 didn't and so I kept on manually calculating the midpoint to get the smallest or closest to the smallest value of the recursion limit that can allow my code to run without RecursionError. My code uses shelve which I hear uses pickle. And that is where the current recursion limit of the python interpreter becomes of importance

@KarlKnechtel, no exceptions. That is all the output.

... And does the program finish, or does it seem to just wait there?

"a value of 15000 worked but a value of 10000 didn't " - what does this mean? What happened when it "worked"? What happened when it "didn't work"?
